# How to do a find/replace using word object in access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working with access 2003 and I want to open a word document from hard disk and replace some text in it and print it (An action similar to a mail merge, in which I have a document and I want to add some text from the current record in access to the document and print it).
I found the following code, but it doesn't change the text in word document.

```
With pDoc.Content.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "hi"
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Text = "hello"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
        Wrap:=wdFindContinue
End With
```

And `pDoc` was set to the opened document.

Any idea why this doesn't change the text? (It runs correctly, but doesn't change hi to hello; the word document is not changed)

Comment: I'm not sure you can use named arguments/parameters when automating word or other office application. Try replacing them with their actual values (which you can find in the object browser - F2 in the VBE)

Answer (score 0):

Citing from my answer to this question:
 [Excel VBA: How to use ListTemplates in Excel to control Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488675/excel-vba-how-to-use-listtemplates-in-excel-to-control-word/8489672#8489672)

> In Excel you need to add a reference to the Word object model:
>
> In the makro editor (Alt+F11) select the "Tools" menu and click
>   "References...". Click the checkbox next to "Microsoft Word Object
>   Library." Click "OK." Now try to run the macro again.
>
> That should get you nearly there.

Maybe all that's missing is the reference to the Word object library.