# Excel VBA: How to use ListTemplates in Excel to control Word?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test()

Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

Dim wrdTbl As Word.Table
Set wrdTbl = wrdDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=wrdDoc.Range, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=1)

With wrdTbl

.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

For r = 1 To 6
    .Cell(r, 1).Range.Text = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1).Value
Next r
End With

' Dim temp3 As ListGalleries
For r = 1 To 6 Step 2
Set temp3 = wrdApp.ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
With temp3
    .NumberFormat = "%1."
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .StartAt = r
End With
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = wrdDoc.Range(Start:=wrdDoc.Range.Rows(1).Range.Start, End:=wrdDoc.Range.Rows(6).Range.End)
rng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=temp3
Next r

End Sub
```

The above codes work well in Word VBA but not in Excel.
Don't know why so difficult to use ListGalleries in Excel to control Word...
Have found millions of entries online but could hardly find one.
Could anyone please help a bit? I'm desperate...
Near nil online coverage on Word VBA...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel you need to add a reference to the Word object model:

In the makro editor (Alt+F11) select the "Tools" menu and click "References...". Click the checkbox next to "Microsoft Word  Object Library." Click "OK." Now try to run the macro again.

That should get you nearly there.

I encountered a few errors that could be compatibility issues. Which version of office are you on? I'm testing all this on Office 2010.

What I had to change to make it work (at least I think so, don't know what exactly you're trying to achieve with that last loop):

```
Set rng = wrdDoc.Range(Start:=wrdTbl.Rows(1).Range.Start, End:=wrdTbl.Rows(6).Range.End)
```

^ Exchanged the range-setting parameters so the whole table gets detected correctly (not sure if this is what you want because this gets called every time the loop is running).

```
rng.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=wrdApp.ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)
```

^ The parameter ListTemplate is expected as a ListTemplate object. You set temp3 to the ListLevel-object that is contained within the ListTemplate. Again, not sure if this is what you're trying to accomplish but according to Office 2010 documentation this is how it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's the illustration:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVZhav-E92w&feature=youtu.be